# Why won't this mirror correctly?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

[image: This is the top of a lamborghini I'm working on.]

The object seems correctly mirrored everywhere except the faces are in the mid section. Blender doesn't even seem to to mirror the complete object. The outlined part is the selected driver side of a car. the left hand part is it's mirror image and it doesn't have all the parts that the selected part has. Is something wrong with my copy of blender?

Comment: There was a glitch in the model. I found and eliminated it. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). If you want, you can post your solution as an answer, for others with a similar problem. It might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Too bad I have memory problems, I forgot what I did.